# When I try to login again, then I get this error:- The getter 'uid' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

When I install and launch the app and login then I dont get the error but if I once logged out then I get this error. Now if the user is logged out why it is even saying  the getter  uid was called on null.

And error takes me to this line and this is inside the Home Screen(the first screen when user logged in). Help me to resolve this:-

```
 matchReference = db.collection("users")
        .doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('Matches');
```

Comment: your `currentUser` is null.

Comment: yes, because user is logged out and if it is logged out then it is going to be null only I think.

Comment: Are you tring to get db collection even you are logged out?

Comment: no, this is inside the Home Screen, comes up only after the user gets logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `uid` when currentUser is null cause error.
you should first check if user exists before calling `uid`

```
    if(auth.currentUser != null){
        matchReference = db.collection("users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).collection('Matches');
      }
```